# Is it usual to obtain very different values of mutual information score using sci-kit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, information-theory, mutual-information

Good day to everyone!

I have a little question related to the function mutual_information_score of sci-kit learn. I've been using it to obtain the mutual information between two datasets A and B; particularly, data in B were generated from a conditional pmf dependent on A.

I've been doing some tests and I found that if I build the data for both distributions with 10k data, the mutual_information_score is very different to that that is obtained with 100k data. I am not sure why do I have these huge changes in the mutual information, given that I am not changing the distributions A or B, I am only sampling more data from random number generators.

I thought that mutual information was a robust measure of uncertainty, and I didn't expect it to change that much with the number of data. I am not sure if these changes are related to the way that mutual_information_score is implemented.

I've been using the function as it is showed in the example of the mutual_information_score documentation (available [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html))

Do you know why do I have this behaviour? Is it usual?

Thank you very much!

UPDATE: I performed tests with other distributions and obtained the same results: lower mutual information scores when increasing the amount of data.

Comment: I'd recommend opening an issue in their repo: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues